# Using a Function in a Callback/Using a SegmentedControl within a Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, callback

I have an app that has UISegmentedControls in each UITableViewCell, it looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezMUJ.png

For every row in which the user selects the "Yes" option, I would like to print the index of the row.

The first step, in this case, would be to use an addTarget on the UISegmentedControl in order to specify a function to handle the Segmented Control's action. However, since I am using a custom segmented control, the addTarget is not available (callback and delegation are the only ways of passing information into the segmented control).

My first question is, is there a way to call a method within a callback?
My second question is, is there an easier way to do this overall? Some people have suggested protocols and delegation for transferring data between the cell and the view controller, but I am not really sure how to do this or that it would be appropriate.

Here is the code I have so far:

import UIKit

class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 150
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    return 10
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath)
    cell.backgroundColor = .green
    return cell

}

func printCellIndexPath(cell: UITableViewCell){

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.register(MyCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellId")

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

class MyCell: UITableViewCell{

```
var myTableViewController: MyTableViewController?

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    setupViews()

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}


let nameLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "Sample Item"
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
    }()

let actionButton = YSSegmentedControl(
    frame: CGRect.zero,
    titles: [
        "Yes",
        "No"
    ],
    action: {
        control, index in
        if index == 1 {
            print ("tapped")
        }
        else{

        }

})

func setupViews(){


    addSubview(nameLabel)
    addSubview(actionButton)
    actionButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-16-[v0]-160-[v1]-16-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": nameLabel, "v1": actionButton]));
    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": nameLabel]))
    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-60-[v0]-60-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": actionButton]))

}
```

}

Where MyCell is my custom cell class and actionButton is the UISegmentedControl that exists within each cell.

Answer (score 0):

To Remove delegation and callbacks why not u make YSSegmentedControl in cellForrowatIndexpath method and there u will pass tag to YSSegmentedControl's object as like that

> actionButton.tag = indexpath.row

and when u click on any segment u will get callback in YSSegmentedControl delegates which are

> func segmentedControl(_ segmentedControl: YSSegmentedControl,
>   willPressItemAt index: Int){
>            print("(segmentedControl.tag)" + "(index)")
>       }
>
> ```
> func segmentedControl(_ segmentedControl: YSSegmentedControl, didPressItemAt index: Int){
>
> }
> ```

From these delegates method u will get YSSegmentedControl row via 
**segmentedControl.tag** and particular button index via **index**